# Do I need to convert str to list?

Tags: python, string, list, task

> rainfall_mi is a string that contains the average number of inches of rainfall in Michigan for every month (in inches) with every month separated by a comma. Write code to compute the number of months that have more than 3 inches of rainfall. Store the result in the variable num_rainy_months. In other words, count the number of items with values > 3.0.
> Hard-coded answers will receive no credit.

Do I need to convert str "rainfall_mi" to list? I know, both ways work.

I know that code executes by both ways. But which's way is better?

```
rainfall_mi = "1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85"
num_rainy_months = 0
rainfall_no = list(rainfall_mi.split(","))
# or
# rainfall_no = rainfall_mi.split(",")
for data in rainfall_no:
    if float(data) > 3:
        num_rainy_months += 1
print(num_rainy_months)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the language you're working with.

Comment: How would you do it without converting to a list?

Comment: rainfall_no = (rainfall_mi.split(","))

Comment: "better" is a meaningless concept until you define strict criteria

Comment: @MaksimMaksimov: `rainfall_no = (rainfall_mi.split(","))` - of what type do you think `rainfall_no` is in this case?

Comment: `split()` already returns a list.

Comment: it's became a "list", but was a "string" before

Comment: I know that list() - convert to a list.

Comment: rainfall_no = list(rainfall_mi.split(","))

Comment: rainfall_no = lrainfall_mi.split(",") or by this way

Comment: "it's became a "list", but was a "string" before" - Exactly. It's the `split` that makes a list. Wrapping that result in `list` does not make the value more of a list.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. It's a list everywhere.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think he means "Do I need to call `list()`?"

Comment: @Barmar: yeah, I figured that much. I was just trying to nudge him into reading the docs on `split`. Perhaps, ineffectively.

Answer (score 1):

`rainfall_mi.split(",")` creates a list. If you uncomment your other example, you can verify

```
rainfall_no = rainfall_mi.split(",")
print(type(rainfall_no))
```

You don't really even need to assign this list to anything. Do the split in the for loop

```
for data in rainfall_mi.split(","):
    if float(data) > 3:
        num_rainy_months += 1
```

And if you want to go full-pythonic, forget the for loop and turn it into a generator to pass to `sum`

```
num_rainy_months = sum(float(rainfall) > 3.0 for rainfall in rainfall_mi.split(",")]
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!! I'm doing first steps in programming )))

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary to call `list()`. `rainfall_mi.split(",")` always returns a list. Since it's already a list, you don't need to convert it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better:

```
rainfall_mi = "1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85"
num_rainy_months = 0
rainfall_no = rainfall_mi.split(",")
# ↑ This returns a list and stores it in rainfall_no. 
# raninfall_no is list

for data in rainfall_no:
    if float(data) > 3:
        num_rainy_months += 1
print(num_rainy_months)
```

You don't need wrap `rainfall_mi.split(",")` by `list()` because it is already a list, and you can use it to do whatever you want to do with the list.